# How can I use cookies to track number of pages between redirects?

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I work for an online web survey company -- our participants are compensated based on the length of the study they participate in. <strike>I'm kind of lazy</strike>To verify the compensation is correct, I would like to track it automatically via cookies to compare with manual counts. Also, every participant might have a different count, so I'd like to be able to more accurately compensate. Time is not very effective since someone could walk away and come back later.

Every survey works like this "participation page".php (domain1) ----> redirect.php(domain2) --> "external survey"(not mine) ----> "endredirect".php (domain2) ---> "Thanks Page"(domain1).

Currently I record the time when you leave the participation page, and when you return to the end page and calculate the number of minutes and estimate how much you should receive.

Is it possible to see a history using a cookie when our participant gets back to the end-page?
If possible I just want to count backwards to the start page.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean *redirect* as in "autmatically send the browser to a different URL"? Sounds like people *click* through your survey pages - which is a different thing.

Comment: They click and are redirected... the first click is to say "let me participate" which goes to a redirect page that finds the survey for them and sends them to the external survey. Same thing on the end, the page they see is a result of a redirect. To be really precise: domain1surveylist - click -> domain2redirect.php -> domain1participation.php -click-> domain2redirect.php -> externalstudy -> domain2end.php -> domain1endpage --- click to close. I want to count between domain2redirect and domain2end pages.

Comment: If this is determining how much people are being compensated, it might be prudent not to take the lazy approach, but to make sure that the system is bulletproof in terms of making sure that the information is correct.

Comment: Removed the "lazy". I can't count for each participant, so I need a way to do it automatically.